# Are there diseases that correlate with an “endocannabinoid deficiency”?

Tags: medical-science, physiology, alternative-medicine, natural-remedies, marijuana

There [was a study published](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15159679) in *Neuro Endocrinology Letters* by Dr. Ethan Russo in 2004 that says many diseases being treated with cannabis correlate with an “endocannabinoid deficiency”, but I cannot read the study or find any more information about this.

Do certain medical conditions correlate with an “endocannabinoid deficiency”?

Comment: Why is this question broad (Are there any diseases?) when the claim is more specific: "Migraine, fibromyalgia, IBS and related conditions display common clinical, biochemical and pathophysiological patterns that suggest an underlying clinical endocannabinoid deficiency that may be suitably treated with cannabinoid medicines."?

Comment: The claim isn't that strong - it is suggesting a possibility that should be investigated experimentally. What would a "Yes" or "No" answer look like?

Comment: @Oddthinking the reason I made the question broad is because the author says “and related conditions”, which seems to imply there are other diseases. For example, there may be evidence that seizures are caused by an endocannabinoid deficiency. A yes answer would include any other studies that have been done to confirm or deny this claim; or perhaps information from Russo’s study that either confirm his claims, or reasons why his claims are weak.

Comment: That sounds a lot more like a question for 
Psychology & Neuroscience SE.

Comment: @Fizz Would the question- as it is- be acceptable there?

Comment: Well, edit it to ask about what you really want to know (i.e. what's not said in the abstract).

Comment: Just for the record: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endocannabinoid_system

Comment: And https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2241751/  This latter contains these words:   *... as well as mice deficient in cannabinoid receptors or the endocannabinoid-degrading enzyme fatty acid amidohydrolase*.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Yes, that’s great information. I’m really just looking for some studies about any deficiency of the endocannabinoid system to confirm or deny whether this is an accepted medical condition.

Comment: @anonymouswho: This abstract is not claiming it is an accepted medical condition. It is saying research is required to establish that.